# Python beginner quest

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm trying to learn python.
I got to the point where we're learning loops "for"
and got a bit of a pickle.
1st assignment was to build a function that will count all spaces, my solution was:

```
def count_spaces(s):
    cnt = 0
    for char in s:
        if char == " ":
            cnt = cnt+1
    return cnt
```

and now I'm trying to build a new function, that can accept string, char
and will return the count of the specific char

for example:

```
print(count_char("Hello world!", " ")
```

and the screen will show 1 (1 space is found)
this is where i got stuck:

```
def count_char(s, c):
    s=[...]
    num = 0
    for x in s:
        if x == x:
            num = s.count(c)
    return num
```

it's returning only 0 ....

please help

Comment: `x==x` is always true.

Comment: This is exactly the same as your first code, the only difference is that you are not looking for a `" "`, but for `c`...

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting your `s` argument at the start of your function:

```
   s = [...]
```

which makes the rest impossible to do.  Don't do that!  :)

If you're allowed to use the `count` method (like your code is doing) you don't need the `for` loop at all:

```
def count_char(s: str, c: str) -> int:
    """The number of character c in string s."""
    return s.count(c)
```

If you wanted to do it without using `count`, you can write it exactly like your `count_space` function, but replace the `" "` with the `c` parameter:

```
def count_char(s: str, c: str) -> int:
    """The number of character c in string s."""
    cnt = 0
    for char in s:
        if char == c:
            cnt = cnt+1
    return cnt
```

Or you could use a `for` comprehension along with the `sum` function:

```
def count_char(s: str, c: str) -> int:
    """The number of character c in string s."""
    return sum(1 if char == c else 0 for char in s)
```

Or you could use a Counter:

```
from collections import Counter

def count_char(s: str, c: str) -> int:
    """The number of character c in string s."""
    return Counter(s)[c]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe instead of

```
if x == x:
```

you need

```
if x == c:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
def count_spaces(s, c):
    cnt = 0
    for char in s:
        if char == c:
            cnt = cnt+1
    return cnt
```

Comment: You could also do `cnt += 1` instead of `cnt = cnt +1`. As an added bonus, if you want to learn about list comprehensions, and do it in one line, do `def count_spaces(s, c): return len([x for x in s if x == c])`. I wouldn't always advise doing this as it consumes memory, but since you're learning about loops, why not!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `s=[...]`. What ever the `...` is, it shouldn't be there because `s` is an input argument and you do not want to change it.

About the code: It should only be:

```
count = string.count(substring)
```

because the `str.count()` implements what you want to achieve.

If you want to avoid using the built in methods and implement it yourself then you should replace

`num = s.count(c)` with `num += 1` and the `x == x` (because x will always equal x and you'll be counting all the characters) with `x == c` like so:

```
def count_char(s, c):
    num = 0
    for x in s:
        if x == c:
            num += 1
    return num
```

Good luck and happy learning!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `s=[...]`. What ever the `...` is, it shouldn't be there because `s` is an input argument and you do not want to change it.

About the code: It should only be:

```
count = string.count(substring)
```

because the `str.count()` implements what you want to achieve.

If you want to avoid using the built in methods and implement it yourself then you should replace

`num = s.count(c)` with `num += 1` and the `x == x` (because x will always equal x and you'll be counting all the characters) with `x == c` like so:

```
def count_char(s, c):
    num = 0
    for x in s:
        if x == c:
            num += 1
    return num
```